# Log4Net SmtpAppender Doesn't Send Mail

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net.

When Application gives an error, I want to send  e-mail just for errors. How should I do that ?

My Config File :

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="SMTPAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SMTPAppender">
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <to value="xxx@xxx" />
      <from value="yyy@yyy" />
      <username value="user" />
      <password value="pass" />
      <subject value="ERROR" />
      <smtpHost value="host" />
      <port value="25" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN" />
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %newline %message%newline%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO"></level>
    </root>
    <logger name="SMTPAppender">
      <level value="INFO"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender"></appender-ref>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to test in NUnit:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TestClass));
        logger.Error("test mail");
    }
}
```

I am probably doing something wrong.

EDIT:

```xml
<logger name="Yuartz.Tests.TestClass">
  <level value="INFO"></level>
  <appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender"></appender-ref>
</logger>
```

```cs
namespace Yuartz.Tests
{
    using log4net;
    using log4net.Config;

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SMTPAppender");
            logger.Error("test mail");
            logger.Info("test mail");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your logging configuration is not in app.config i would recommend you to add it to there. And  ensure that log4net configured properly otherwise call XmlConfigurator.Configure();

Comment: Please "remove unit"-testing tag. It has no relevance in your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example you use the full name of the type (TestClass) to retrieve your logger. It will use this name to resolve the logger or create a new one when not found.

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TestClass));
```

If you want this line of code to return the SMTPAppender logger, then you need to rename it in the config as follows:

```
<logger name="Yuartz.Tests.TestClass">
    ...
</logger>
```

If you don't want to change the configuration then you need to retrieve your logger by its actual name. The following returns the logger named "SMTPAppender".

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SMTPAppender");
```

My advice is to just change the name in the configuration and keep retrieving the logger by type as you currently do.

Also make sure that you read your configuration.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. sinanakyazici, Make sure you understand how log4net's namespace-based hierarchy works. In your case, you configured a logger that uses the SmtpAppender, but named it so that your Classname doesn't match. As a consequence, all you get in your test is the fallback (root logger), which has no appenders at all. If you want to see what's going on in your log4net configuration process, add the following to your app.config. `<appSettings><add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/></appSettings>`. Sometimes this helps finding issues with your Xml.

Comment: @Christophe Geers :  I tried what you said but I still doesnt work. Edited my question.

Comment: Well you renamed the logger to Yuartz.Tests.TestClass, the full type name of your test class. But now you retrieve the logger with the name "SMPTAppender". You need to retrieve it by type as you did before if you rename the logger. Either you leave the logger named "SMTPAppender" and retrieve it by that name or you rename the logger to your type name and retrieve it by type. Don't do both.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to read Log4Net configuration before your unit test runs.

see this article [How to use Log4Net in Unittests](http://blog.developerslog.net/?p=61)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling somewhere `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` ?
If so, sometimes sending mail simple fail because the antispam catch it, so make sure you check with your system admin if there is something marked as a spam somewhere.